# Using Google Drive contents using Google Drive API without sending access tokens for each request

Tags: swing, security, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am writing an application that can modify an spreadsheet in Google Drive, but the problem is that each time I try to access Drive contents it asks for access token  as per the OAuth2 specification which I have to generate manually after browsing through the following link:

```
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto&client_id=<THE_CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

Anybody having idea if its possible to either get this token through Drive API or through any other medium, The client application will be in the form of a Java Swing application in which there will be text fields the text inserted in those fields will be added as a row in the spreadsheet hosted on the Google Drive.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the token manually the first time, but then you can reuse it. I guess this is a duplicate?
[Stored Credential from google api to be reused java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861178/stored-credential-from-google-api-to-be-reused-java)

[must I click "Allow Acess" every time I connect? Google Drive SDK API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275738/must-i-click-allow-acess-every-time-i-connect-google-drive-sdk-api?rq=1)

[EDIT] Sorry, I did not see the date.