# Refresh Access Token with OAuth 2.0 Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I would like to implement the auto-refresh method to obtain a new Access Token given the Refresh Token already taken from the first authorization flow.

Which method or list of methods should I call to do that? I'm using Java and OAuth 2.0 for Web Application. Given [OAuth 2.0 WebApplication](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/authorization), what should I add in this code to get everything to work correctly?

Comment: I posted an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42517728/266531 that I think addresses what you are after with more detail

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The link you give in your question implements Google OAuth 2.0 authorization by using [Google APIs Client Library for Java](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2). And
this library has implemented function of refresh access token .

So what you need is using [Class GoogleRefreshTokenRequest](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.18.0-rc/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleRefreshTokenRequest.html) in this library.

> This class is Google-specific implementation of the OAuth 2.0 request to refresh an access token using a refresh token as specified in [Refreshing an Access Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6).

And its java doc also gives a sample usage:

```
static void refreshAccessToken() throws IOException {
try {
  TokenResponse response =
      new GoogleRefreshTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
          "tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA", "s6BhdRkqt3", "7Fjfp0ZBr1KtDRbnfVdmIw").execute();
  System.out.println("Access token: " + response.getAccessToken());
} catch (TokenResponseException e) {
  if (e.getDetails() != null) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getDetails().getError());
    if (e.getDetails().getErrorDescription() != null) {
      System.err.println(e.getDetails().getErrorDescription());
    }
    if (e.getDetails().getErrorUri() != null) {
      System.err.println(e.getDetails().getErrorUri());
    }
  } else {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

}

And This is [another usage](https://github.com/jcmiranda/FreeTimeFinder/blob/master/src/calendar_importers/GCalAuth.java) you can refer to.

You can add code below in CredentialManager.java, and when you need to refresh token, call this method.

```
public Credential refreshAccessToken(String refreshToken, String clientId, String clientSecret) throws IOException {
try {
  TokenResponse response =
  new GoogleRefreshTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
      refreshToken, clientId, clientSecret).execute();
  System.out.println("Access token: " + response.getAccessToken());
  return buildEmpty().setAccessToken(response.getAccessToken());
} catch (TokenResponseException e) {
  if (e.getDetails() != null) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getDetails().getError());
    if (e.getDetails().getErrorDescription() != null) {
      System.err.println(e.getDetails().getErrorDescription());
    }
    if (e.getDetails().getErrorUri() != null) {
      System.err.println(e.getDetails().getErrorUri());
    }
  } else {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

another method is use DataStoreCredentialRefreshListener

> Access protected resources using the GoogleCredential. Expired access tokens will automatically be refreshed using the refresh token (if applicable). Make sure to use [DataStoreCredentialRefreshListener](http://javadoc.google-oauth-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.18.0-rc/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/DataStoreCredentialRefreshListener.html) and set it for the credential using [GoogleCredential.Builder.addRefreshListener(CredentialRefreshListener)](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.18.0-rc/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.Builder.html#addRefreshListener(com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.CredentialRefreshListener)).

Comment: Just calling the refreshAccessToken() method, Are my credentials automatically refreshed? Or after obtaining a TokenResponse i have to build and Empty Credential, adding/substituting the new Access Token and Re-load Credential from AppEngineCredentialStore? because i'm switched on an other example that is DrEdit (Java Version) using https://developers.google.com/drive/web/examples/java (https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/blob/master/java/src/com/google/drive/samples/dredit/CredentialManager.java)

Comment: Yes, calling this method will not update your credential automatically, you need to reset your credential with new token.

Comment: Thank you very much! you save me and many others. I think also that you can use even (as return): return buildEmpty().setFromTokenResponse(response);  And it will work as well. Am i correct? :-)

Comment: @OwenCao When i use the first function in my class , I am getting cannot fnd symbol error for TokenResponse and GoogleRefreshTokenRequest. Can you tell how to solve this. Whether i need to include jar files?

Comment: @Santhosh Yes, you need google-api-java-client, https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/

Answer (score 3):

```
final GoogleCredential credential = new Builder()
        .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
        .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
        .setClientSecrets(OAuth2Provider.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, OAuth2Provider.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)
        .build()
        .setRefreshToken(refreshToken);

credential.refreshToken(); // do not forget to call

String newAccessToken = credential.getAccessToken();
```

Then you can use an object like *UserTokens*:

```
public class UserTokens {

    public final String accessToken;
    public final String refreshToken;

    public UserTokens(String accessToken, String refreshToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
        this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    }

}
```

... and then store it in DB like:

```
TokenRepository tokenRepository = new PersistentTokenRepository();
tokenRepository.store(userTokens);
```

---

#### Notes

- `OAuth2Provider` is my custom class where I keep client's *id* and
  *secret*
- `TokenRepository` is a custom interface that has methods like `store()` and
  `get()`
- `PersistentTokenRepository` is custom the implementation of the upper
  interface where you can store tokens in SQL or NoSQL databases like [GAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine)